# Mask formatter that accepts different types of date formats

Tags: java, swing, date, swingx

I have to display a date in the format MM/dd/yyyy. The date to be displayed can be in any of the following formats

1. MM/dd/yyyy
2. MM/yyyy
3. yyyy

If only month and year are available and day is not available then I have to display the date in the format MM/__/yyyy leaving the day blank.

If only year is available and day and month are not available then I have to display the date in the format __/__/yyyy leaving day and month blank.

I'm able to display it properly if whole date is available i.e. day, month and year using mask formatter.
MaskFormatter formattedDate = new MaskFormatter("##'/##'/####");
but not able to display it if day or month is missing.

Is there any way to display the date leaving date and month blank?

Comment: Can you please add the complete code that you have tried?

Comment: Can you create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ? Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later have a class for each of your needs:

- [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for date-only, without time-of-day, and without time zone.
- [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) for a year and month but no date, and no time zone.
- [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) for just a year.

For example:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) );
```

> ym.toString(): 2018-02

All three offer a `format` method to which you pass a `DateTimeFormatter` object. You can define custom formatting patterns in that `DateTimeFormatter`. Search Stack Overflow as this has been covered many times already.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/__/uuuu" );
String output = ym.format( f );
```

> 02/__/2018

### ISO 8601

By the way, consider using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats to display these values as text. The format for a date is `YYYY-MM-DD`, and for a year-month, `YYYY-MM`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).